# Set custom rendering styles on an SXA component to be enabled by default

Tags: sxa

When adding a component to a placeholder, how would I go about setting default values for custom styles in the rendering parameters so that certain styles are enabled automatically for the user when they creating a component in Experience Editor?

i.e. in the Styling section of the component properties modal, set a custom CSS class to a default value:

[image]

Comment: I think that a more concrete example would make the problem easier to be understandable. What is the component you are using? And what would be the CSS value you want to add and on which field that value should go?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Standard Values on rendering

The only one out of the box solution is doing it via Standard Values on rendering parameters.

**Pro:**

- no code
- easy

**Cons:**

- default values defined globally per rendering parameters

### ExecutePageEditorAction

Add additional processor to `ExecutePageEditorAction` pipeline.

Take a look at `Sitecore.XA.Feature.PageStructure.Pipelines.ExecutePageEditorAction.FillColumnSpliterDefaultGridValues` as an example where default grid values are assigned to the splitter columns.

**Pro:**

- fast

**Cons:**

- executed only in EE, so if rendering will be added via CE, a code will not be invoked

### PresentationProcessing

Add additional processor to `PresentationProcessing` pipeline.

Take a look at `Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Presentation.Pipelines.PresentationProcessing.SetDefaultParameters`.

Be careful. This pipeline is launched during save, not like **ExecutePageEditorAction** only during drag&drop in EE (AddRendering action)

**Pro:**

- executed both for EE and CE

**Cons:**

- potentially might cause problems with performance if the implementation will be heavy

### Summary

If you can live with fact that editors are able to add rendering with default CSS classes in EE only I would recommend you **ExecutePageEditorAction**